# How to find the String with more numbers?

Tags: java

Trying to find the String with more numbers. Output should me the text which fulfills the condition, how many charachters are in String.

```
public static String countNr(String a) {
        int count = 0;
        int maxNr = 0;

        String text= null;

        int i;
        for( i =0 ; i < a.length(); i++){
            char c = a.charAt(i) ;
            if(text==null || Character.isDigit(c)){
                count++;
                if( count < maxNr){
                  maxNr  = count ;
                  text+= a ; // in output alway null
                }
            }
        }

        return text + ":" + a.length() + "-" +  i;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the input, what is the output, what is currently happening?

Comment: If you're trying to find the string containing the most numbers, you presumably should be looking at more than one string.

Comment: yes user shoud write some sentences

Comment: There are some logical issues in your code... `text` will be `null` in the first iteration, which makes the condition in your `if` statement **always true**, no matter if the first character is a digit or not. Then you increment `count` and check if it is less than `maxNr`, which stays 0. The result is a `false` in the following `if` condition and `text` stays `null`. That will happen in every iteration. Consider nesting `if` statements here...

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your `foreach` loop. This should work fine.

```
        for( i =0 ; i < a.length(); i++){
        char c = a.charAt(i) ;
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            count++;
            if( count > maxNr){
                maxNr  = count;
            }
        }
```

You have other problems with your method. First, you are passing only one string, so the comparison is pointless ; second, your "text" variable is a local variable and will be reset on each consecutive call to your method.

You should pass an array of strings, or make "text" global (and assign it the full string if it meets the condition). Either solution will normally return the single string with the most digits.

Comment: In this loop i'm trying to look if the string has numbers and then that string trying to save in a variable , because output should be the sentence that fullfills the condition.